# Setting dtype during read_csv for a dataframe with two headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't find this asked before, apologies if it has.

I want to specify the data types of different columns using read_csv, but for a dataframe with two headers, as below:

```
df = read_csv('data.csv', header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
```

Also, does using two headers affect the performance much more than using a single header?

Many thanks.

Comment: use the dtype attribute https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: But if there are two headers, how do I refer to a named column?

Comment: with multi line header, that becomes a multi-index. you can access them as tuple, defining both levels of the header or access the first level header.